# Spring Batch not able read xml file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

while creating spring batch application i got following error

```
No exception of type BeansException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
```

Below is my code

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
public class App {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BeansException  {     
            ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("D:\\job-report.xml"); 

    }
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: And where you get the error? Is is a compile error?

Comment: I have copied the program and can not see any problem. try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Sorry can't get you?!

Comment: I only tried to check your compile error. But in my eclipse it is not showing any error. I can not run your project, because i do not have your `D:\\job-report.xml`

Comment: are you using exception in jour job to catch error and retry or something similar? post relevant job xml